# Finding any arbitrary integer point on a line with rational slope and intercept

Tags: number-theory, integers

Consider the equation of a simple line:

$$
f(x)=mx+b
$$
with the additional constraint that $m$ and $b$ are guaranteed to be rational numbers:

$$
f(x) = \frac{m_n}{m_d}x + \frac{b_n}{b_d}
$$$$
m_n, m_d, b_n, b_d \in \mathbb{Z}; m_d, b_d \neq 0
$$

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805260/finding-integer-coordinates-from-slope) affirms the intuitive fact that for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(x+km_d) \in \mathbb{Z}$ holds true for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So it is quite easy to determine the location of the 'next' integer coordinate pair on a line, but only if you are given an integer coordinate pair that $f(x)$ passes through to start with.

If you are not given a starting point, it seems to be very difficult to find one without doing manual iteration.

I am looking for a function that, given the rational slope and y-intercept of an arbitrary line, returns *any* integer $x$ such that $f(x)$ is also an integer. There is no constraint on where $(x, f(x))$ lies on $f(x)$. Both coordinates just have to be integers and $f(x)$ must pass through the point.

In mathematical terms, construct a function $p(m_n, m_d, b_n, b_d)$ such that $f(p(m_n, m_d, b_n, b_d)) \in \mathbb{Z}$ holds true for all $m_n, m_d, b_n, b_d$

*With the additional criterion that $p$ must be expressed in terms of one or more other functions on $m_n, m_d, b_n, b_d$ and cannot require any kind of iteration or manual guessing-and-checking.

Comment: There may be no such point – consider $f(x) = x+\frac 12$.

Comment: Then the function I am searching for should also be able to determine that no integer points exist on the line with a given slope and intercept.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\frac qr x + \frac st$ is an integer if and only if $qtx + rs$ is a multiple of $rt$. In other words, finding integer values of $\frac qr x + \frac st$ is the same problem as solving the *linear congruence* $qtx + rs \equiv 0 \pmod{rt}$ in the variable $x$. Solving linear congruences (including deciding when they have no solutions) is algorithmically easy, and many descriptions of the algorithm can be found via a web search. In brief:

- Divide all of $qt$, $rs$, and $rt$ through by their greatest common divisor, yielding $ax+b\equiv 0\pmod c$.
- If $\gcd(a,c)>1$, then there are no solutions.
- Otherwise, the solutions are given by the congruence $x\equiv -a^{-1}b\pmod c$.

Comment: This is satisfactory for single cases of specific rational coefficients. I am assuming that there does not exist a function that can be plotted in a continuous domain and accomplishes what this does. The GCD function is only valid over the integers. Technically that is what I am looking for, is a graph function to extract integer $(x, f(x))$ out of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, not just $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming $m_n/m_d$ and $b_n/b_d$  in simplest form)

The necessary and sufficient condition is that $b_d | m_d$ (this is equivalent to Greg's answer, try to prove it).

This is because:
$$y = x \cdot \frac{m_n}{m_d} + \frac{b_n}{b_d}$$
$$\implies m_dy - m_n x = m_d\left(\frac{b_n}{b_d}\right)$$
The condition is necessary because the LHS is an integer, and sufficient by [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

The solution can be found by the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) or by computing $m_d^{-1} \pmod{m_n}$ (which exists since they are coprime), and setting $y= m_d^{-1} \cdot kb_n$ where $k = m_d/b_d$.

Comment: See the final constraint; the function cannot involve iteration like the Euclidean algorithm. Also, I am looking for a function that can be plotted on $\mathbb{R}$, not just the integers.

Comment: @JW in number theory there aren't functions which you can compute just by plugging in the values.

Comment: And number theoretic functions don't go well on $\Bbb R$

Comment: Without the Euclidean Algorithm and manual guessing, there is no other way to compute the modular inverse, so I don't think your demand is possible.